# .NET web config

Tags: iis, web-config

Due to certificate mapping I have added a rule in web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
       <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
         <match url="(.*)" /> 
         <conditions> 
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
         </conditions> 
         <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
       </rule> 
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But however my url isn't loading correctly

For example `https://www.example.com/xyz/five.jpg` is loading correctly in mobile and other applications
but however my earlier URL in DB mapped with some URL like above.

What is not loading
`http://example.com/xyz/five.jpg` is loading into `https://www.example.com/xyz/five.jpg` instead of `https://example.com/xyz/five.jpg`...

Comment: What browser do you use? And do you have some redirection from non-WWW to WWW on DNS side? Merely the rewrite rule above on IIS, won't ever change URL in that way.

Comment: This is happening across all browsers

Comment: Apart from this rule, I don't have anything else configured in web.config

Comment: If you comment out the https redirection rule in your web.config and then browse to `http://example.com` does it redirects you to `http://www.example.com` ? If it does it means you have redirect setup at DNS level.

Comment: `http://example.com` redirects `https://www.example.com` instead of `https://example.com`

Comment: will check and see @MohsinMehmood

Comment: Thanks it was the DNS entry... removed and its working fine..